# My friend found a piece of paper inside his bag and i wanted to know what it is written in it its like taweeZ

Tags: image, helping, tawiz

[image]
It is a piece of paper found inside the bag of my frnd looks like taweez or something

Answer (score -1):

A Muslim should fear only Allah and put all his trust on Allah. There is no reason to fear some piece of paper, whatever be written in it.

> ... fear Him, and fear none but Allah ... [Quran 33:39](https://quran.com/en/al-ahzab/39)

Comment: Yeah i know but its imp to know  thats y i asked...i dont fear from these kind of things bcoz i know allah will protect us